# App crashes when installed through iTunes

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

There is a strange issue I am facing when I install app(.ipa file) through iTunes not directly through xcode, App crashes when installed through iTunes while same app runs perfect when ran directly xcode. I am currently using xcode 7.1.1 and iOS 8.4. Below is the snippet of crash report

```
    Date/Time:           2015-12-09 17:24:42.431 +0530
    Launch Time:         2015-12-09 17:23:34.722 +0530
    OS Version:          iOS 8.4 (12H143)
    Report Version:      105

    Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
    Exception Subtype: EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN at 0x0751d002
    Triggered by Thread:  28
```

I am trying to upload video to server using [this library](https://github.com/nuclearace/Socket.IO-Client-Swift) which works fine when ran through xcode while crashes when installed otherwise.

Comment: It's the device added to the signing provisional profile on Apple Dev's Console?

Comment: try to run the app in release configuration.

Comment: yes there are differences between building for debug and building for release. I had optimisation issues.

Comment: A variety of things could cause this problem. As you can't really trace the issue in your debugger you might try implementing Crashlytics in your app. This is a free library and if you are familiar with CocoaPod you can add it to your app. If the app crashes the crash info is sent up to the web and it may show you the root cause of your crash along with the line in the code where it crashed.

Comment: I have integrated crashlytics into my app but when app crashes it always show line number 0